# Access value by location in sorted pandas series with integer index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a pandas Series with an integer index which I've sorted (by value), how I access values **by position** in this Series.

For example:

```
s_original = pd.Series({0: -0.000213, 1: 0.00031399999999999999, 2: -0.00024899999999999998, 3: -2.6999999999999999e-05, 4: 0.000122})
s_sorted = np.sort(s_original)

In [3]: s_original
Out[3]: 
0   -0.000213
1    0.000314
2   -0.000249
3   -0.000027
4    0.000122

In [4]: s_sorted
Out[4]: 
2   -0.000249
0   -0.000213
3   -0.000027
4    0.000122
1    0.000314

In [5]: s_sorted[3]
Out[5]: -2.6999999999999999e-05
```

But I would like to get the value 0.000122 i.e. the item in **position** 3.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace the line

```
b = np.sort(a)
```

with

```
b = pd.Series(np.sort(a), index=a.index)
```

This will sort the values, but keep the index.

**EDIT:**

To get the fourth value in the sorted Series:

```
np.sort(a).values[3]
```

Comment: I exchanged the row with this sample_mean_series_sorted = pandas.Series(np.sort(sample_mean_series), index=sample_mean_series.index). But it did not sort my issue. To clearify, I want to retrieve a specific row in the sorted Series. An example, get value for row four which is 0.000122.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`iget`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#api-changes-to-integer-indexing) to retrieve by position:
*(In fact, this method was created especially to overcome this ambiguity.)*

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series([0, 2, 1])

In [2]: s.sort()

In [3]: s
Out[3]: 
0    0
2    1
1    2

In [4]: s.iget(1)
Out[4]: 1
```

.

The behaviour of `.ix` with an integer index is noted in the [pandas "gotchas"](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html#integer-indexing):

> In pandas, our general viewpoint is that **labels matter more than integer locations**. Therefore, with an integer axis index only label-based indexing is possible with the standard tools like `.ix`.
>
> This deliberate decision was made to prevent ambiguities and subtle bugs (many users reported finding bugs when the API change was made to stop “falling back” on position-based indexing).

#### Note: this *would* work if you were using a non-integer index, where `.ix` is not ambiguous.

For example:

```
In [11]: s1 = pd.Series([0, 2, 1], list('abc'))

In [12]: s1
Out[12]: 
a    0
b    2
c    1

In [13]: s1.sort()

In [14]: s1
Out[14]: 
a    0
c    1
b    2

In [15]: s1.ix[1]
Out[15]: 1
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning this [feature request on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1052).