# Get value of a Pandas GroupBy Object

Tags: pandas

```
group.Units[group['Channel'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('F'))]
```

gives me a Series

```
0    4
```

How can I get only the value from this GrupBy Object? I.e.:

```
4
```

Comment: Say you assigned your Series to `s` you'd do: `s.values[0]`. This is roughly a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14455746/42346

Comment: You're most welcome. Happy coding to you

Answer (score 0):

```
group.Units[group['Channel'].map(lambda x: x.startswith('F'))].values[0]
```